# Cannot Start Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: jenkins

I had an old Jenkins running from the packages, and wanted to update to the latest version. According to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-20-04, I executed:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins
```

This went through well, but Jenkins wasn't able to start. Since the old Jenkins version was running on Java 8, and I needed Java 11, I updated `/etc/init.d/jenkins` (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621263/jenkins-fails-when-running-service-start-jenkins):

```
JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
#JAVA="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

But still, starting does not work:

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Calling `status` returns the following:

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins.service
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-17 14:28:24 CEST; 20s ago
    Process: 125679 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 125679 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 17 14:28:24 irpsim.X.de systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 17 14:28:24 irpsim.X.de systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Jul 17 14:28:24 irpsim.X.de systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 17 14:28:24 irpsim.X.de systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 14:28:24 irpsim.X.de systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
```

As in the stackoverflow question, the journalctl didn`t really help:

```
Jul 17 14:28:24 X.uni-leipzig.de systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit jenkins.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 14:28:24 X.uni-leipzig.de systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit jenkins.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 48074 and the job result is failed.
```

I tried to `su` to `jenkins`, but its not allowed to start Jenkins there:

```
jenkins@irpsim:/home/dgr$ /etc/init.d/jenkins
The jenkins init script can only be run as root
jenkins@irpsim:/home/dgr$ exit
exit
root@irpsim:/home/dgr# /etc/init.d/jenkins start
Starting jenkins (via systemctl): jenkins.serviceJob for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This seems to be an issue with the package and my configuration, but I cannot find another way to debug this. Is there maybe a known issue or some further way to further debug this?

**EDIT**: A similiar problem occured here (https://serverfault.com/questions/1051031/jenkins-installation-fails-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-dpkg-error-processing-package-j), but this could be fixed by updating Java. Since I have Java 11 installed and usable, I assume that this is not the problem.

Comment: check `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`